Where are Debug symbols located for .NET Core
I'm trying to find debug symbols for Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.dll which is part of the .NET SDK 8.0.303. These instructions point me to a tarball in the form, dotnet-symbols-sdk-<version>-<rid>.tar.gz, but for the life of me, I cannot find that tarball anywhere to download. I've tried the dotnet-symbol app, but it doesn't find the PDB.
I also tried cloning the .net SDK repo and building with .\build.cmd -c Release /p:DebugSymbols=true /p:DebugType=portable, but the resulting DLL had a slighly different file size and version than the installed SDK DLL and the Visual Studio debugger wouldn't take the PDB. I installed version 8.0.303 of the SDK and cloned tag v8.0.303 of the repo.

I don't need any additional tools and I already have the library. I'm looking for the method to retrieve the PDBs.

@KenWhite This isn't a recommendation question, it's a request for help locating the official location of some resource inside of a development SDK. The close reason you mention is for questions which ask for other people to suggest (recommend) a tool or a resource to OP to use to achieve some task.

@TylerH: Retracted.
